# What is direct access to a plugin in wordpress dangerous and why is defining a constant ABSPATH important?

Tags: php

I'm developing my first wordpress php plugin. In it, I do have some pretty sensitive information in my php files. Like for instance, I'm having my plugin create a bunch of tables in the database.

According to the tutorial I'm following, it mentions restricting direct access to the plugin php file by putting the following code at the top of each file in the plugin directory:

```
defined ('ABSPATH') or die ("No Script Kiddies");
```

First of all, I'm not even sure what the ABSPATH variable refers to?

Second, what harm could be done if this code isn't included at the top of every .php file in the plugin directory?

Thanks for helping explain this to me.

Comment: This is a common way to prevent direct access to your plugin file URI. `ABSPATH` is a constant defined by wordpress, so - if the user try to load directly your page - this constant is not defined and the script die.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen other guards in Wordpress plugins.  ABSPATH is the absolute path to the Wordpress directory and will be initialised if Wordpress starts before including the plugin code or file.

It's a precautionary measure.

Let's imagine a fictitious plugin called 'house keeping'.

Plugin files:

```
house-keeping.php 
includes/delete-all-posts.php
```

The delete all posts file contains just the code to delete all posts, but usually relies on other tasks procedures in the plugin code before being run, like a function call in house-keeping.php:

```
function hk_delete_all_posts() {
    include 'includes/delete-all-posts.php'
}
```

Imagine the pain if an attacker exploited the flaw in the plugin code and ran delete-all-posts.php by itself.

(I realise that delete-all-posts.php would need other Wordpress dependencies, but let's not worry about that.)

Answer (score 0):

depends on your code. since wordpress code files are exposed to everyone you should protect direct php access to them.

the constant check is the most simple way to disable direct script access.